# php, how to grab data from an multidimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

i have an array that looks like this:

```
foreach($obj as $key => $value)
{
print_r ($obj);
}

Array
(
[id] => 24991526504444
[name] => 21test
[picture] => http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-sn4/276505_2499152255_s.jpg
[link] => http://apps.facebook.com/test/vote=6189373
[likes] => 1
[category] => Website
[parking] => Array
    (
        [street] => 0
        [lot] => 0
        [valet] => 0
    )

[payment_options] => Array
    (
        [cash_only] => 0
        [visa] => 0
        [amex] => 0
        [mastercard] => 0
        [discover] => 0
    )
)
```

how can i get the data from this array, for ex the `id`, or the `likes`.

i've tryed `echo $key['likes']` or  `echo $key[$value['likes']]` and some more combinations and it doesn't work

any ideas?
thanks

Comment: I don't think you understand how a foreach loop works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$key` isn't your array, `$obj` is your array. You should be using `$obj['likes']` or `$obj['parking']['street']`. You don't have to enumerate the keys to access the keys/values within the object, just use `$obj`.

Also, your `foreach` doesn't make sense:

```
foreach($obj as $key => $value)
{
    print_r ($obj);
}
```

This reads "For each key in the array, print the entire array". You don't have to loop at all, the whole purpose of `print_r` is to recursively print the contents of an array for you with no looping.  Just use

```
print_r($obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read the [manual on arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

You don't need a loop to access an array.  What you want can be done simply with 
`$obj['id']` or `$obj['likes']`.

Answer (score 1):

According to this:

```
foreach($obj as $key => $value)
{
print_r ($obj);
}
```

the array you have displayed is actually the full structure of `$obj` and not any of its key=>value pairs.

So you should just need:

```
echo $obj['likes'];
echo $obj['id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using foreach, that means you are iterating array elements, you should be using

```
    $obj['likes']
```

should return the value on the array (1 in your case).

And for the multidimensional ones

```
    $obj['payment_options']['cash_only']
```

should return the value (0 in your case)